# Expo google authentication failure

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin, expo-go

I have been trying to implement google sign In in my expo app. Unfortunately it seems to fail after choosing the account with which to sign in with.[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSpb4.jpg)

below is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Button, TouchableOpacity, Text,StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import { makeRedirectUri, useAuthRequest } from 'expo-auth-session';
import Constants from 'expo-constants'; // Used to get the Expo app's manifest

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

const discovery = {
  authorizationEndpoint: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth',
  tokenEndpoint: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
};

const redirectUri = makeRedirectUri({
   useProxy: true,
   scheme:'tirulauth',
   path:'exp://127.0.0.1:8081'
  });

export default function App() {

  const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: '537144176465-2bvcj0e2mkun082f384lbgeqa1vl5meq.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
      redirectUri:'https://auth.expo.io/@adamjohnson/tiralauth',
    },
    discovery
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === 'success') {
      console.log(response);
    }
  }, [response]);

  const handleGoogleLogin = () => {
    promptAsync();
  };


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleGoogleLogin} style={{width:'80%',fontWeight:600,fontSize:16,backgroundColor:'blue',padding:10}}>
        <Text style={{color:'#FFF',textAlign:'center'}}>SIGN IN</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

It had to authenticate and give me the user email and name in the console